# Keycloak spring adapter - check that the authToken is active with every http request

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, grails3

Problem I want to solve:

For every call made to the service I want to check that the token is active, if it isn't active I want to redirect the user to the login page.

> Current setup:  Grails 3.2.9 ,  Keycloak 3.4.3

Ideas so far:

This article looked promising: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/json-web-token-jwt-spring-security-real-world-example-boris-trivic

In my security config I added a token filter

```
@Bean
public TokenAuthenticationFilter authenticationTokenFilter() throws Exception {
    return new TokenAuthenticationFilter();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure http
    http
        .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/sso/login") // Override Keycloak's default '/'
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/assets/*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN") 
            .and()
        .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());      
}
```

My TokenAuthenticationFilter just prints out the request headers at the moment :

```
public class TokenAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter { 

    private String getToken( HttpServletRequest request ) {

        Enumeration headerEnumeration = request.getHeaderNames();
        while (headerEnumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            println "${ headerEnumeration.nextElement()}"
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {        
        String authToken = getToken( request );
    }

}
```

Which returns:

- host
- user-agent
- accept
- accept-language
- accept-encoding
- cookie
- connection
- upgrade-insecure-requests
- cache-control

The code/logic I want to implement in the filter is something like:

```
KeycloakAuthenticationToken token = SecurityContextHolder.context?.authentication 

RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext context = token.getCredentials()

if(!context.isActive()){
    // send the user to the login page 
}
```

However I'm lost as to how to get there.
Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand, your question is about "how to check the token is active?" and not "how to redirect the user to login page?".

As I see you added the tag "spring-boot" and "keycloak" maybe you could use "Keycloak Spring Boot Adapter". Assuming you use the version 3.4 of Keycloak (v4.0 still in beta version), you can found some documentation [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.4/securing_apps/index.html#_spring_boot_adapter).

If you can't (or don't want to) use Spring Boot Adapter, here is the part of the `KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter` [source code](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/20f24bffc43f61186d1e41d6aec9a098ea19afea/adapters/oidc/spring-security/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/springsecurity/filter/KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.java#L60-L73) that could be interesting for your case:

```java
KeycloakSecurityContext keycloakSecurityContext = getKeycloakPrincipal();
if (keycloakSecurityContext instanceof RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext) {
    RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext refreshableSecurityContext = (RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext) keycloakSecurityContext;
    if (refreshableSecurityContext.isActive()) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

and here is the (Java) [source code](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/20f24bffc43f61186d1e41d6aec9a098ea19afea/adapters/oidc/spring-security/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/springsecurity/filter/KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.java#L88-L100) of the getKeycloakPrincipal method:

```java
private KeycloakSecurityContext getKeycloakPrincipal() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if (authentication != null) {
        Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();

        if (principal instanceof KeycloakPrincipal) {
            return KeycloakPrincipal.class.cast(principal).getKeycloakSecurityContext();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

And if you want to understand how the Authentication is set in the SecurityContextHolder, please read this [piece of (Java) code](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/20f24bffc43f61186d1e41d6aec9a098ea19afea/adapters/oidc/spring-security/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/springsecurity/filter/KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java#L186-L210) from `KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter`:

```java
@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (authResult instanceof KeycloakAuthenticationToken && ((KeycloakAuthenticationToken) authResult).isInteractive()) {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
        return;
    }

    ...

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);

    ...

    try {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } finally {
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    }
}
```

As an alternative you could also check this github repository of dynamind:
https://github.com/dynamind/grails3-spring-security-keycloak-minimal

Hoping that can help.
Best regards,
Jocker.

Comment: Hi Jocker , thanks for taking the time to answer - I suppose a better title for what I want to do is "User fails authentication when token has expired".  I use the keycloak-spring-security-adapter - maybe this could be where I am going wrong?

Comment: Hi JJHolloway,
Maybe you should try to make it work with [Keycloak Spring Boot Adapter](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.4/securing_apps/index.html#_spring_boot_adapter).
This Spring Boot Module will instantiate a Filter to check the Token validity. You could then configure this module with few properties.